# Is $L^1(\Omega)$ isomorphic to $l¹$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request

I'm trying to understand a statement in the Brezis book, that $L^1(\Omega, \mu)$ is not reflexive. He divides the problem into two parts: one in which $\mu$ is a non atomic measure and another in which $\mu$ is purely atomic, i.e, $\Omega$ consists of a infinite countable number of distinct atoms.

**My question:** In the second case in which $\Omega$ consists of a infinite countable number of distinct atoms, how to show that $L^1(\Omega)$ isomorphic to $l¹$?

Comment: If there are a _finite_ number of distinct atoms, then the space $L^1(\Omega,\mu)$ is finite-dimensional and hence reflexive, unless "atom" doesn't mean what I think it means. It should be "countably infinitely many atoms", I think.

Comment: Yes, are you right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $\mu$ is purely atomic and there are countably many atoms, call them $x_1, x_2, \ldots$. Let $f\in L_1(\Omega)$. Then

$$\int\limits_{\Omega} f(x)\,\mu({\rm d}x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int\limits_{\{x_n\}} f(x)\,\mu({\rm d}x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(x_n).$$

This shows that the map $f\mapsto (f(x_n))_{n=1}^\infty\in  \ell_1$ is an isomorphism. As point out by Daniel Fisher, it need not be isometric. To make it such, just define

$$f\mapsto \left(\frac{f(x_n)}{\mu(\{x_n\})}\right)_{n=1}^\infty.$$

Comment: I don't think an atom is required to have measure $1$, so you'd need to weight with the measure of the atom.

Comment: Based on your solution I thought of the following: If $\{A_i\}$ are the atoms of $\Omega$ the we have that $\int f_{\Omega}d\mu=\int_{\cup A_i}fd\mu=\sum \int_{A_i}f d\mu$, so the isomorphism must be $f\mapsto (\int_{A_i} fd\mu)$? This are right?

Comment: @OEmpaladordeCabras Yes, that is right. And although it has not yet been mentioned, it is worth noting that that is an __isometric__ isomorphism.